# Avoiding a List-Within-A-List With Spark SQL collect_set

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to find an efficient solution to an annoying behavior in Spark SQL.

I am preprocessing massive files for loading into Druid which involves the following operations:

```
val dfIn = spark.read.json(inPath)
val df = dfIn.select("A","B","C","D").filter($"B" === 1 || $"B" === 2)
val dfFinal = dfx.groupBy("B","C","D").agg(collect_set("A"),count("*"))
dfFinal.write.json(outPath)
```

The field "A" is a JSON list, and when collect_set is executed I end up with a list as the only element inside another list. This is a big problem with Druid ingestion because its parser does not recognize this and treats the list as empty. I just want to get rid of this useless outer list.

Solutions like exploding the (very long) lists to create separate rows then collecting them seem extremely expensive for what, in other programming environments, is basically an output formatting issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a udf. Assuming your column A is a list of string you can try something like this:

```
def flattenSet(arr: Seq[Seq[String]]): Seq[String] = arr.flatten

newDfFinal = dfFinal.withColumn("AsetName", udf(flattenSet)($"AsetName"))
```

where AsetName is the name of the collect_set column.

Do note that unless you explode first, the collect_set would not promise uniqueness across the values but instead across combinations (the original lists). If you do want to promise uniqueness across the values then you should probably do collect_list instead of collect set and change the flattenSet function to include just unique values (arr.flatten.distinct)